# NSFileManager moveItem: Comment field missing

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

When moving a folder with comments field in objective c, the comments field become empty at destination,here is the code,

```
[FileManager moveItemAtPath:oldPath toPath:newPath error:&error]
```

how can i fix this issue,how can i fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be supported, however [here is an extension](https://cheddar.ics.uci.edu/code/svn/giornata/trunk/Source/Application/CocoaExtensions/NSFileManagerExtendedAttributes.m) that might help you.

Comment: NSFileManager * FileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc]init];

Comment: when i am moving it manually it supported. then why not using code..?

Comment: Because the API doesn't support it.

Comment: is there any other way to do it..

Comment: Yeah using the extension I pointed out.  Get the metadata of the folder you want to move first, move the folder using `NSFileManager` and then re-apply the metadata after the move.

Comment: thanks @Droppy..I will try that..and let u know the result.. have good day..